# Returning Calculation on column values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I've follwing code

```
select (WYPOZYCZENIA.DATA_ZWR -WYPOZYCZENIA.DATA_WYP+1)* --count days between dates +1
    (WYPOZYCZENIA.ST_VAT /100+1)* --generates 1.23 value to count VAT
    (POJAZDY.CENA_ZL) --gets price per day
  from POJAZDY POJAZDY,
    WYPOZYCZENIA WYPOZYCZENIA 
 where WYPOZYCZENIA.ID_POJAZDU=POJAZDY.ID_POJAZDU
    and WYPOZYCZENIA.ID_WYPOZYCZENIA :=1
```

This code is to calculate price that include vat and is calculated from day price and days between that I want to calculate using data from columns. But this code doesn,t work, how to write it properly? Apex returns ORA-00920: invalid relational operator.

Comment: `:=1`, remove colon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the colon in the criteria for `ID_WYPOZYCZENIA`. Last line should read:

```
and WYPOZYCZENIA.ID_WYPOZYCZENIA = 1
```

It's also a good idea to specify your JOIN type, consider:

```
SELECT (WYPOZYCZENIA.DATA_ZWR -WYPOZYCZENIA.DATA_WYP+1)*
    (WYPOZYCZENIA.ST_VAT /100+1)*
    (POJAZDY.CENA_ZL)
  FROM POJAZDY POJAZDY
  JOIN
    WYPOZYCZENIA WYPOZYCZENIA 
    ON WYPOZYCZENIA.ID_POJAZDU = POJAZDY.ID_POJAZDU
  WHERE WYPOZYCZENIA.ID_WYPOZYCZENIA = 1
```